# Email arn does not belong to your account SES Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cognito, amazon-ses, serverless-framework

I'm trying to confirm a user my sending a confirmation email. Cogntio requires the arn for email I set up with SES. Below is my template.

When I deploy with serverless I get:

```
An error occurred: UserPool - Email arn does not belong to your account. (Service: AWSCognitoIdentityProvider; Status Code: 400; Error Code: NotAuthorizedException; Request ID: a4ce4fc2-020b-11e8-bc29-7ff8569f2cc7).
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
  Resources:


    SESRole:
      Type: "AWS::IAM::Role"
      Properties:
        AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
          Version: "2008-10-17"
          Statement:
            - Effect: "Allow"
              Principal:
                Service:
                  - "cognito-idp.amazonaws.com"
              Action:
                - "sts:AssumeRole"
        Policies:
          - PolicyName: "CognitoSESPolicy"
            PolicyDocument:
              Version: "2008-10-17"
              Statement:
                - Effect: "Allow"
                  Sid: stmtXXXXXXX
                  Action:
                    - "ses:SendEmail"
                    - "ses:SendRawEmail"
                  Resource: "arn:aws:ses:eu-west-1:XXXXX:identity/XXXXXXX"

    # Creates a user pool
    UserPool:
      Type: "AWS::Cognito::UserPool"
      Properties:
        UserPoolName: ${self:service}-user-pool
        EmailConfiguration:
          ReplyToEmailAddress: XXXXX
          SourceArn:
            Fn::GetAtt: [SESRole, Arn]
        EmailVerificationSubject: "verification code"
        EmailVerificationMessage: "Please click the link below to verify your email address. {####} "
        Schema:
          - Name: name
            AttributeDataType: String
```

Comment: is `arn:aws:ses:eu-west-1:XXXXX:identity/XXXXXXX` created on the same AWS account?

Comment: It should be, I only have one Aws account although I created a user in it I am using the root account on the console and cli

Comment: Oh wait, I created a user for the cli... I'm logging into the console with the root account to set up SES. Is that my problem?

Comment: Logging to my user account which has full admin permissions, I can see everything I created in SES so I have sufficient privileges in both

Answer (score 3):

In AWS SES Home click on the verified email then click on Identity Policies. Check there
is Cognito-SES-Policy is there or not. If it is not there then click on
 CreatePolicy -> Custom policy and paste this code:-

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
             "Sid": "stmnt6857725459985",
             "Effect": "Allow",
             "Principal": {
                "Service": "cognito-idp.amazonaws.com"
             },
             "Action": [
                 "ses:SendEmail",
                 "ses:SendRawEmail"
             ],
             "Resource": "arn:aws:ses:Region:<ACCOUNT-ID>:identity/sample@example.com"
         }
     ]
 }
```

2.Use IdentityARN in the Cloud Formation template for SourceARN under EmailConfiguration.

```
EmailConfiguration:
          ReplyToEmailAddress: XXXXX
          SourceArn:
            "arn:aws:ses:Region:<ACCOUNT-ID>:identity/sample@example.com"
```